# How to get the byte representation of an IP address from a SockAddr in Rust?

Tags: rust

A call to the function [`recv_from()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.recv_from) returns a (length, [`SocketAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.SocketAddr.html)) tuple. There is no method on this enum to extract an IP address as a byte array, however it does contain a [`IpAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html) enum which can be obtained with the [`ip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.SocketAddr.html#method.ip) function. The `IpAddr` contains an [`Ipv4Addr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html) or `Ipv6Addr` struct, which have a function called [`octets()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html#method.octets) that does exactly what I need. Is it possible to get access to this from a `SocketAddr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, but ultimately you need to account for the fact that an address could be v4 or v6, and handle accordingly, using pattern matching. Basically:

```
match sa.ip() {
    IpAddr::V4(ip) => /* something with ip.octets() which is a [u8; 4] */,
    IpAddr::V6(ip) => /* something with ip.octets() which is a [u8; 16] */,
}
```

for example, if you wanted to be future-unfriendly, you could

```
let octets = match sa.ip() {
    IpAddr::V4(ip) => Ok(ip.octets()),
    _ => Err("Not an IPv4 Address"),
};
```

which returns a successful Result for v4 addresses, but errors on v6 ones. I don't really know Rust, but it looks like the only really right way to handle the type disparity between the return values of `octets()` in the two cases is either to wrap the result in your own enum, or else just avoid it by only working with the octets inside of an appropriate pattern match.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you! I came up with a sort of hacky solution to the result disparity by casting the result to a vector. In my case I already know if the IP is v4 or v6.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I ended up using looks like this:

```
let ip_bytes = match addr.ip() {
    IpAddr::V4(ip) => ip.octets().to_vec(),
    IpAddr::V6(ip) => ip.octets().to_vec(),
};
```